# Why are Clean Master, Daily Racing, DU Booster, MP3 Downloader, SnapTube and TouchPal installing themselves?

Tags: applications, malware

One day I found myself having some weird apps in my phone I didn't remember installing. After uninstalling them, they appeared again after after some time.

These apps are:

- Clean Master
- Daily Racing
- DU Booster
- MP3 Downloader
- SnapTube
- TouchPal

How did they install themselves and howcome they appear again after uninstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this was most probably caused by **SnapPea**.

Not only this app installed itself after connecting my phone to my PC (where I did have SnapPea program installed), but also installed those 5 more rubbish apps. If I go to Google Play on the web and look up those self-installed apps, it shows me they are not actually installed. If I open the apps up in Google Play on my phone, it gives me uninstall option, but I can't rate them.

As SnapPea cannot be installed from Google Play, even though it looks quite professional on both phone and PC, the product is certainly a malware.

I strongly recommend uninstalling SnapPea from everywhere.